# Select method not selecting Kendo UI Grid row

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I can't seem to get the select kendo ui grid (web) method to select a row (or anything for that matter).  I read in another post to include the div id in the selector, but that doesn't help either.  For simplicity, I am trying to do this in telerick's example here: http://dojo.telerik.com/oNeR

I would expect that the first row is selected automatically by adding:

```
          var gridRow = $("#rowSelection").data("kendoGrid");
          gridRow.select("tr:eq(0)");
```

Full Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/selection">
<style>html { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
<title></title>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/styles/kendo.common.min.css"      rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <script src="../content/shared/js/orders.js"></script>

    <div id="example">

        <div class="demo-section k-header">
            <h4>Grid with multiple row selection enabled</h4>
            <div id="rowSelection"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="demo-section k-header">
            <h4>Grid with multiple cell selection enabled</h4>
            <div id="cellSelection"></div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#rowSelection").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        data: orders,
                        pageSize: 6
                    },
                    selectable: "single",
                    pageable: {
                        buttonCount: 5
                    },
                    scrollable: false,
                    navigatable: true,
                    columns: [
                        {
                            field: "ShipCountry",
                            title: "Ship Country",
                            width: 300
                        },
                        {
                            field: "Freight",
                            width: 300
                        },
                        {
                            field: "OrderDate",
                            title: "Order Date",
                            format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
                        }
                    ]
                });

                $("#cellSelection").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        data: orders,
                        pageSize: 6
                    },
                    selectable: "multiple cell",
                    pageable: {
                        buttonCount: 5
                    },
                    scrollable: false,
                    navigatable: true,
                    columns: [
                        {
                            field: "ShipCountry",
                            title: "Ship Country",
                            width: 300
                        },
                        {
                            field: "Freight",
                            width: 300
                        },
                        {
                            field: "OrderDate",
                            title: "Order Date",
                            format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
                        }
                    ]
                });
            });
          var gridRow = $("#rowSelection").data("kendoGrid");
          gridRow.select("tr:eq(0)");
        </script>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On first glance the grid code is correct. I am almost certain your issue is that your script is executing and calling the methods on the grid before it can be initialised - certainly before it can be bound. In the first case I'd expect to see errors in the console because gridRow would be defined, in the second I'd expect it to fail silently because the selector tr:eq(0) won't match anything.

Try attaching a function to the [databound event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#events-dataBound) of the grid as follows-

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function selectFirstRow(event) {
            event.sender.select("tr:eq(0)");
        }

        $("#rowSelection").kendoGrid({
            dataBound: selectFirstRow,
            dataSource: {
                data: orders,
                pageSize: 6
            },
            selectable: "single",
            pageable: {
                buttonCount: 5
            },
            scrollable: false,
            navigatable: true,
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "ShipCountry",
                    title: "Ship Country",
                    width: 300
                },
                {
                    field: "Freight",
                    width: 300
                },
                {
                    field: "OrderDate",
                    title: "Order Date",
                    format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
                }
            ]
        });

        $("#cellSelection").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: orders,
                pageSize: 6
            },
            selectable: "multiple cell",
            pageable: {
                buttonCount: 5
            },
            scrollable: false,
            navigatable: true,
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "ShipCountry",
                    title: "Ship Country",
                    width: 300
                },
                {
                    field: "Freight",
                    width: 300
                },
                {
                    field: "OrderDate",
                    title: "Order Date",
                    format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Reading about dataBound I would think that works.   But, it doesn't.  It throws TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'o.options') when executing the select method.  Also doesn't work in the Kendo dojo test app.

Comment: @user1489995 I have fixed your Dojo at http://dojo.telerik.com/EKOm - you needed to declare your datasource slightly differently. Are you able to include orders.js in your question (don't have to use real data). Is it an array of object?

Answer (score 0):

In your grid configuration your selectable property is incorrect:

```
selectable: "single"
```

set this to `selectable: "row"`